# What’s the first Indian alien story?

Tags: aliens, history-of

India doesn’t have a strong Sci-Fi history. Here are some examples of Indian works which featured aliens:

- *Koi Mil Gaya* (2003) movie featured aliens
- *Aaryaman* (2002) TV series was full of aliens as it was a copy of Star Wars.
- *Shaktimaan* TV series [featured aliens in late 90’s](https://youtu.be/uK46vOe6Mdc) (aliens came to Earth literally in Star Wars’ Imperial Star Destroyers).
- *Captain Vyom* TV series featured aliens in late 90’s.
- I recently rediscovered an alien story published in Champak magazine (December 1995 issue).
  [image]
  Same issue has a candy ad featuring spaceship and aliens:
  [image: Hajmola candy, introducing two new flavours: Nakhrilee Kamrakh and pangbaaz plum]
  (This ad was famous in 90’s)

Which Indian Sci-Fi work first featured aliens?

Comment: The article “Indian Science Fiction: History and Contemporary Trends” by Srinarahari M H, and [this blog post,](https://indiascifiarvind.blogspot.com/2010/03/mainstream-and-genre-sf-emergence-and.html) might be good starting points for research. These describe “Aaschry Vrittaant” (A Strange Tale) by Ambika Datt Vyas as the first science-fiction story in India, not counting SF-like elements in traditional legends, and “Chandrlok ki Yatra”(A Journery to Moon ) by Babu Keshav Prasad as another early example. I do not know whether either feature aliens.

Comment: @Davislor "A Strange Tale" is very like "Journey to the Center of the Earth" - no aliens

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To set a mark for written science fiction, I'll suggest *Shukra Bhraman*  ("Travel to Venus") by [Jagadananda Roy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagadananda_Roy), written in 1892 and published in 1914. According to *[Indian Science Fiction: Pattern, History and Hybridity](https://www.amazon.in/Indian-Science-Fiction-Hybridity-Dimensions/dp/1786836661)* by Suparno Banerjee, it "describes an adventure on Venus and encounters with alien creatures".

Answer (score 12):

The first Indian film featuring the concept of aliens was Kalai Arasi released in 1963 starring M.G Ramachandran. [Kalai Arasi Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalai_Arasi)

[image]

Its main plot was about aliens abducting a dancer so that she could teach the aliens how to dance and sing.

I'll try finding other Indian media featuring sci-fi but as far as movies go this was the first.